# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 about opencv

Tags: ios, architecture, opencv, i386

I am studying opencv for ios now.After I download example codes from github.com/macmade, i complie and run the program, everything is OK. However, when i add some opencv codes as bellow:

```
IplImage* img = 0;
int height,width,step,channels;
uchar* data;
int hIndex,wIndex,cIndex;
img = cvLoadImage("tapme.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if (!img) {
    NSLog(@"img cannot load");
    return;
}

height = img->height;
width = img->width;
step = img->widthStep;
channels = img->nChannels;
data = (uchar*)img->imageData;

NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d:%d",height,width,step,channels);
```

Then i compile the program again, everything is OK too. But when errors happen when linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_cvLoadImage", referenced from:
-[MainViewController showPic:] in MainViewController.o
```

I have tried almost all methods in stackoverflow, but the result is still not so good. Anyone have a good idea to fix the bug, waiting for ur help and thank u.

Answer (score 1):

When you build for the simulator, the linker will need a library for i386 architecture. When you build for a device, the linker will need a library for arm architecture. Do your simulator build settings point to the correct library?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer, but how can i point the settings to specified libeary? I cannot find it in Xcode4 and i set the architectures to standard armv6 and armv7